# Загрузка файла, если есть куки

Tags: безопасность, cookie, php

Кто-нибудь может знает, как это сделать: 
в диске `С:` есть, так сказать, созданные мной нужные куки. 
Захожу на `сайт/admin.php` и он открывает, если есть куки нужные.
Как это сделать? Есть опыт? Поделитесь или скажите что читать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])&&$_COOKIE['cookie_name']=='value'){
    //Ваш код
}
else{
    die('');
}
```

Где cookie_name - ваши куки на диске C:, value - их содержимое. В зависимости от требований безопасности код может усложняться.
Устанавливаются куки функцией set_cookie():
 
http://www.php.su/functions/?setcookie
http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
Извлекаются из супер-глобального массива $_COOKIE.